# show child component depend on data from parent in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to archive the functionality for Material Dialog. I want to make parent popup component , which contain all my popups that i use in my app.
The structure looks like this

```
parent-popup-component 
|
| - popup1
| - popup2
| - popup3
...component.ts ...component.html
```

And inside other component i call parent-popup-component like this

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ParentPopupComponent, {
  data: { dialogName: 'popup1' },
});
```

Inside parent-popup.component.html i store all my popups and pass data object with needed popup name to child popup

```
<popup1 [data]='data'></popup1>
<popup2 [data]='data'></popup2>
<popup3 [data]='data'></popup3>
```

How can i show child-popup template inside parent popup when i make a call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply achieve it using `*ngIf` on the basis of data you are getting like this -

```
<popup1 [data]='data' *ngIf="data.dialogName == 'popup1'"></popup1>
<popup2 [data]='data' *ngIf="data.dialogName == 'popup2'"></popup2>
<popup3 [data]='data' *ngIf="data.dialogName == 'popup3'"></popup3>
```

Comment: this was the case, but what if i have about 200 popups templates is it possible to do it only pass data to child popup and maybe return something?